# how to trigger youtube video from image click mobile device

Tags: mobile, youtube

There was a similar question posted few days ago but it was deleted... I use fancy box to popup a youtube video when the user clicks on thumbnail.

But in mobile version i wish to trigger mobile's video player instead of playing video on popup so the user can watch the video in fullscreen...

Is there any way?!